# Hard bricked with no bootloader and black screen

Tags: bootloader, redmi

I have a redmi 7 onclite hard bricked in EDL mode (9008), my phone got black screen, no bootloader. I would like to know how to fix it. I don't have an authentication account, only a normal account Xiaomi. I tried to flash with QFIL, i got sahara error or I/O error. In fact, i think it's a bootloader problem and i have no idea how to fix it. Somebody can help me.